# Chat (XMPP) messaging platform

Tags: c#, xmpp, chat

I would like to encapsulate different messaging platforms (Google Talk, Facebook Chat) for my users - of course it will be using XMPP.

I will be writing the server in C# and the client in Flex (AIR).

- Do I need to keep track of all the message in the server?
- What would be the best practice for notifying users about a new message?

  - Polling?
  - Push? (How does C# works with Flex)

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to write a server at all. Your Flex (AIR) client has to connect to Facebooks or Googles XMPP server only. I suggest to pick a client library from here: http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/ and start coding.